# Suggestionbox performance issue

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am facing some performance issue with suggestion box.

I have a page with 200 rows each row has 2 suggestion box for text field, the page takes more than 20 seconds to load,

```
   <rich:dataTable
     id="detail_table"
     width="auto"
     value="#{testBean.testList}" 
     var="record" 
     headerClass="GrayBackgroundHeader"
     rowKeyVar="row"
     ajaxRendered="true"
     rowClasses="TableRowOdd,TableRowEven">
     <f:facet name="header">
         <rich:columnGroup>
             <h:column>
                 <h:outputText value="ColumnA" />
             </h:column>
             <h:column>
                 <h:outputText value="ColumnB" />
             </h:column>
         </rich:columnGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <rich:columnGroup>
         <h:column>
             <h:inputText value="#{record}" id="text1" />
             <rich:suggestionbox id="suggestionBoxId1" for="text1" selfRendered="true"/>
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
             <h:inputText value="#{record}" id="text2" />
             <rich:suggestionbox id="suggestionBoxId2" for="text2" selfRendered="true"/>
         </h:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
 </rich:dataTable>
```

Above are my test codes. Am I using the suggest box incorrectly or pls help to advice to improve the performance.

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

Is using paging an option? if so you might want to check the following example
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=dataModel&cid=295707
use a datascroller and to improve performance even better you can implement your own SerializableDataModel in which you will be able to retrieve only the amount of rows that you want in a page

Comment: Sorry that for the requirement, we can't use paging in this page